# MDB DataTable text-align on th and td in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, datatables, mdbootstrap

I'm generating a sortable table in reactjs using `mdbreact` like so

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

const tableData = {
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'first_name',
            label: 'First Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'last_name',
            label: 'Last Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'age',
            label: 'Age'
        }
    ],
    rows: [
        {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Smith',
            age: 29
        },
        {
            first_name: 'Jane',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            age: 37
        }
    ]

class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MDBDataTable data={tableData} />
        )
    }
}

export default Table;
```

(the above is a simplification of the table i'm working with)

At the moment i'm using something similar to the below to target the first 5 `th` elements in css:

```
th:nth-of-type(-n+5) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

But is there a way to either apply a class of some sort by column or cell or apply styling on the js level?

Specifically i would like to apply a class to the **age** `th` and `td` elements, wherever they may lie in the column order

Comment: I have also tried using the `attributes: {className: 'target-this-pls'}` in the `tableData.columns` array on the age column object, but this only applies the class to the top header row, the bottom row remains unaffected. Also I have no idea if I can apply this logic to cell elements.

Comment: According to [mdbootstrap support](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/react/attributes-in-mdbdatatable-not-working/), only attributes for columns currently. And they will add this feature in the near future.